# AES decryption works in python but not in .NET

Tags: c#, python, vb.net, aes

This python code works perfectly and decrypts the cipher text:

```
import sys, hexdump, binascii
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
class AESCipher:
def __init__(self, key):
     self.key = key

def decrypt(self, iv, data):
     self.cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
     return self.cipher.decrypt(data)

key = binascii.unhexlify("0602000000a400005253413100040000")
iv = binascii.unhexlify("0100010067244F436E6762F25EA8D704")
hex_str_cipher = "d690a9d0a592327f99bb4c6a6b6d4cbe" 
ciphertext = binascii.unhexlify(hex_str_cipher)
raw_un = AESCipher(key).decrypt(iv, ciphertext)
password = raw_un.decode('utf-16')
print(password)
```

but trying to recreate it in VB.NET like so:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim AesEnc = System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create()
    AesEnc.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
    AesEnc.KeySize = 128
    AesEnc.Key = HexToBytes("0602000000a400005253413100040000")
    AesEnc.IV = HexToBytes("0100010067244F436E6762F25EA8D704")
    Dim EncryptedBytes As Byte() = HexToBytes("d690a9d0a592327f99bb4c6a6b6d4cbe")
    Using MemStrm As New IO.MemoryStream(EncryptedBytes)
        Using CryptStrm As New CryptoStream(MemStrm, AesEnc.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
            Dim PlaintextBytes(EncryptedBytes.Length - 1) As Byte
            CryptStrm.Read(PlaintextBytes, 0, PlaintextBytes.Length)
            Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(PlaintextBytes))
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Public Function HexToBytes(HexString As String) As Byte()
    Dim ByteLength = HexString.Length \ 2
    Dim Bytes(ByteLength - 1) As Byte
    For i = 0 To ByteLength - 1
        Bytes(i) = Convert.ToByte(HexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16)
    Next
    Return Bytes
End Function
```

Always fails on the call to `CryptStrm.Read` with the error "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed"

I've done AES encryption/decryption in .NET plenty of times before using the routine above, so I can't understand why this fails as if the key/IV is incorrect when its identical to what the python script is using. Any ideas?

Comment: Who is encrypting the data? Your python code does not specify any padding, so I assume it uses the default padding (whatever it is I don't know). From my experience, cross programming language encryption/decryption problems always boils down to having different paddings.

Comment: @OguzOzgul I've no idea what language was originally used to encrypt it. Its from a third party program. All I know is the python code works and my .NET code doesn't even though they both appear to be doing the exact same thing. I'll look into the padding stuff now though thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @OguzOzgul for his comment about padding, I tried adding this line to my .NET code and now it works perfectly

```
AesEnc.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros
```